# Why does form display incorrectly in IE7/8?

Tags: html, css

Why does this form display incorrectly in IE7/8?

- Firefox (correct):
  http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/9610/contactfirefox.png
- IE (incorrect):
  http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/2742/contactiexplorer.png

Here is the code:

```
/*-----Contact Form----------------*/

.fb-container {
    width: 425px;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif !important;
    }

.fb-signuptxt {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #68a64c;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }   

.fb-tptxt {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #006600;
    font-size: 15px;

    }

.fb-form {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-top: solid #a0a9c0 1px;
    border-bottom: solid #a0a9c0 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.fb-input {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 250px;
    border: solid #bdc7d8 1px;
    }

.fb-select {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 34px;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: solid #bdc7d8 1px;
    float: left;
    }   

.fb-txt-left {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #1d2a5b;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: left;
    }

.fb-input-right {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    }

.fb-button-left {
    margin: 8px 0 0 125px;
    float: left;
    }

.fb-error {
    width: 366px;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    background-image:url(../images/error_warning_icon.svg.med.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dd3c10;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 7px 3px 7px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    }
/*Button*/
.button_outside_border_green {
    width: 105px;
    border: solid #3b6e22 1px;
    border-bottom: solid #2c5115 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

.button_inside_border_green {
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
    background-color: #68a64c;
    border-top: solid #98c286 1px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

div.button_inside_border_green:active {
    background-color: #609946;
    }
#boxSuccess {

            width:300px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color:#8DBCF5;
            background-image:url(../check-blue-icon.gif);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 5px 5px;
            border:1px solid;
            border-color:#666666;
            font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:18px;
            color: white;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding: 16px 0 0 76px;
        }
```

contact html code

```
<div id="contactheading">
          <div id="contactheadingTxt">Please use this form to contact us for General enquries. If you need<br />support
please use the Support option in the menu. Thank you.</div></div><br />
    <div class="fb-container">
    <div class="done" style=display:none;></div>
    <div class="fb-signuptxt">Contact Us </div>
    <div class="fb-tptxt">Contact us with a general enquiry. </div>
    <div class="fb-form">
        <div class="fb-txt-left">First Name:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <input type="text" class="fb-input" name="firstname" 
id="firstname"/>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">Last Name:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <input type="text" class="fb-input" name="lastname" 
id="lastname"/>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">Your Email:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <input type="text" class="fb-input" name="email" id="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">Re-enter Email:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <input type="text" class="fb-input" name="emailr" id="emailr"/>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">New Password:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <input type="password" class="fb-input" name="pass" id="pass"/>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">I am:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <select class="fb-select" name="sex" id="sex">
            <option value="0">Select Sex:</option>
            <option value="1">Female</option>
            <option value="2">Male</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-txt-left">Birthday:</div>
        <div class="fb-input-right">
            <select class="fb-select" name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month">
                <option value="0">Month:</option>
                <option value="1">Jan</option> 
                <option value="2">Feb</option> 
                <option value="3">Mar</option> 
                <option value="4">Apr</option> 
                <option value="5">May</option> 
                <option value="6">Jun</option> 
                <option value="7">Jul</option> 
                <option value="8">Aug</option> 
                <option value="9">Sep</option> 
                <option value="10">Oct</option> 
                <option value="11">Nov</option> 
                <option value="12">Dec</option> 
            </select> 
            <select class="fb-select" name="birthday_day" id="birthday_day">
                <option value="0">Day:</option>
                <option value="1">1</option> 
                <option value="2">2</option> 
                <option value="3">3</option> 
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option> 
                <option value="6">6</option> 
                <option value="7">7</option> 
                <option value="8">8</option> 
                <option value="9">9</option> 
                <option value="10">10</option> 
                <option value="11">11</option> 
                <option value="12">12</option> 
                <option value="13">13</option> 
                <option value="14">14</option> 
                <option value="15">15</option> 
                <option value="16">16</option> 
                <option value="17">17</option> 
                <option value="18">18</option> 
                <option value="19">19</option> 
                <option value="20">20</option> 
                <option value="21">21</option> 
                <option value="22">22</option> 
                <option value="23">23</option> 
                <option value="24">24</option> 
                <option value="25">25</option> 
                <option value="26">26</option> 
                <option value="27">27</option> 
                <option value="28">28</option> 
                <option value="29">29</option> 
                <option value="30">30</option> 
                <option value="31">31</option>              
            </select> 
            <select class="fb-select" name="birthday_year" id="birthday_year">
                <option value="0">Year:</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option> 
                <option value="2010">2010</option> 
                <option value="2009">2009</option> 
                <option value="2008">2008</option> 
                <option value="2007">2007</option> 
                <option value="2006">2006</option> 
                <option value="2005">2005</option> 
                <option value="2004">2004</option> 
                <option value="2003">2003</option> 
                <option value="2002">2002</option> 
                <option value="2001">2001</option> 
                <option value="2000">2000</option> 
                <option value="1999">1999</option> 
                <option value="1998">1998</option> 
                <option value="1997">1997</option> 
                <option value="1996">1996</option> 
                <option value="1995">1995</option> 
                <option value="1994">1994</option> 
                <option value="1993">1993</option> 
                <option value="1992">1992</option> 
                <option value="1991">1991</option> 
                <option value="1990">1990</option> 
                <option value="1989">1989</option> 
                <option value="1988">1988</option> 
                <option value="1987">1987</option> 
                <option value="1986">1986</option> 
                <option value="1985">1985</option> 
                <option value="1984">1984</option> 
                <option value="1983">1983</option> 
                <option value="1982">1982</option> 
                <option value="1981">1981</option> 
                <option value="1980">1980</option> 
                <option value="1979">1979</option> 
                <option value="1978">1978</option> 
                <option value="1977">1977</option> 
                <option value="1976">1976</option> 
                <option value="1975">1975</option> 
                <option value="1974">1974</option> 
                <option value="1973">1973</option> 
                <option value="1972">1972</option> 
                <option value="1971">1971</option> 
                <option value="1970">1970</option> 
                <option value="1969">1969</option> 
                <option value="1968">1968</option> 
                <option value="1967">1967</option> 
                <option value="1966">1966</option> 
                <option value="1965">1965</option> 
                <option value="1964">1964</option> 
                <option value="1963">1963</option> 
                <option value="1962">1962</option> 
                <option value="1961">1961</option> 
                <option value="1960">1960</option> 
                <option value="1959">1959</option> 
                <option value="1958">1958</option> 
                <option value="1957">1957</option> 
                <option value="1956">1956</option> 
                <option value="1955">1955</option> 
                <option value="1954">1954</option> 
                <option value="1953">1953</option> 
                <option value="1952">1952</option> 
                <option value="1951">1951</option> 
                <option value="1950">1950</option> 
                <option value="1949">1949</option> 
                <option value="1948">1948</option> 
                <option value="1947">1947</option> 
                <option value="1946">1946</option> 
                <option value="1945">1945</option> 
                <option value="1944">1944</option> 
                <option value="1943">1943</option> 
                <option value="1942">1942</option> 
                <option value="1941">1941</option> 
                <option value="1940">1940</option> 
                <option value="1939">1939</option> 
                <option value="1938">1938</option> 
                <option value="1937">1937</option> 
                <option value="1936">1936</option> 
                <option value="1935">1935</option> 
                <option value="1934">1934</option> 
                <option value="1933">1933</option> 
                <option value="1932">1932</option> 
                <option value="1931">1931</option> 
                <option value="1930">1930</option> 
                <option value="1929">1929</option> 
                <option value="1928">1928</option> 
                <option value="1927">1927</option> 
                <option value="1926">1926</option> 
                <option value="1925">1925</option> 
                <option value="1924">1924</option> 
                <option value="1923">1923</option> 
                <option value="1922">1922</option> 
                <option value="1921">1921</option> 
                <option value="1920">1920</option> 
                <option value="1919">1919</option> 
                <option value="1918">1918</option> 
                <option value="1917">1917</option> 
                <option value="1916">1916</option> 
                <option value="1915">1915</option> 
                <option value="1914">1914</option> 
                <option value="1913">1913</option> 
                <option value="1912">1912</option> 
                <option value="1911">1911</option> 
                <option value="1910">1910</option> 
                <option value="1909">1909</option> 
                <option value="1908">1908</option> 
                <option value="1907">1907</option> 
                <option value="1906">1906</option> 
                <option value="1905">1905</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-button-left">
            <div class="button_outside_border_green" id="sub">
            <div class="button_inside_border_green">
            Send
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just for the heck of it, make the `.fb-container` slightly wider and see what happens.

Comment: @Sparky672. took it up to 500px, still the same grrrrrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific?

One thing that stands out is any floated element you have that has a horizontal margin, it's likely the double margin bug is occurring so put `display:inline;` on any element that is floated and has horizontal ( left, right ) margins.

Comment: i have just posted some grabs to see the obvious problem. thanks

Comment: what do you mean horizontal margin?

Comment: left or right margins. `margin:30px;` is 30px to all sides, so that means horizontal... I would just add `display:inline` to any floated element with margins set as a baseline.

Comment: @meder. tried that and it is still the same. for instance on the code: .fb-txt-left {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #1d2a5b;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: left;
 display:inline;
 
    }

Comment: on *all* the elements that have horizontal margins?

Comment: BTW, providing HTML would help. Sounds like you need to wrap them in a `class="field"` div and use `clear:both;`

Comment: @meder. have updated original question with html code. thanks

Comment: @meder. applied clear:both; to .fb-txt-left and voila. working in ie.yippee. thanks ever so much.